# How can I remove a byte of type []byte

Tags: arrays, go, byte

I have a variable `cmd` that returns `[50 48 ... 50 53 10]`

It's possible to remove any bytes of this var? In my case, I want to remove the last byte [10] == LF (Line Feed) to obtain: `[50 48 ... 50 53]`

P.S.: I have not found any similar question because the function `bytes.Trim(cmd, "\x10")` does not work for me, or maybe, I don't use it fine...

Comment: 0x10 equals 16; you meant to do `\xA`.

Comment: Yes it's truth! Thank you @TimCooper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte{50, 48, 50, 53, 10}
    fmt.Println(b)
    b = bytes.TrimSuffix(b, []byte{10}) // Line Feed
    fmt.Println(b)

    b = []byte{50, 48, 50, 53, 10}
    fmt.Println(b)
    b = bytes.TrimSuffix(b, []byte("\n")) // Line Feed
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Output:

```
[50 48 50 53 10]
[50 48 50 53]
[50 48 50 53 10]
[50 48 50 53]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such built-in method to do this, but you can still do it like this:

```
cmd := []int{1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}
expected := cmd[:len(cmd)-1])
```